# Run Android NDK .so library in normal Java

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

How Can I call methods .so shared object compiled to Android NDK in normal Java?

Comment: Take a look at Java Native Interface (JNI) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

Comment: I saw that, but System.load always give me No such file or directory error on load the .so NDK lib

Comment: Hmm sorry then I have no idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "normal Java" you mean on your regular machine and not an Android device, you can't. Even if you build x86 NDK libraries, those libraries have many dependencies on the Android system libraries.